# Memory table limit MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using MEMORY storage engine for storing data produced by multiple joins and complex data operations that are otherwise very slow. I need to store a high amount of data, so I increased the max heap table size from the 16MB default, to 2GB. When I check the value for the max_heap_table_size variable, I get the 2GB I've set. However, after executing the query for filling the table, I get an error that the limit has been reached after reaching 16MB. Am I missing something?

Comment: As per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size), `Setting this variable has no effect on any existing MEMORY table, unless the table is re-created with a statement such as CREATE TABLE or altered with ALTER TABLE or TRUNCATE TABLE.`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Not sure how I missed it :)